# MVEL script execution error "no context" after library update

Tags: mvel

I have a problem with MVEL running very simple 2-lines script like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {}
for (int j=0; j < 1; j++) {}
```

With MVEL library of version 2.2.3 and higher there is always such error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: no context

This "no context" error message doesn't specify a problem in script and I'm not sure if it's a regression issue in library or some new special thing in MVEL syntax requirements. According to the spec the standard C-style for-loop should be supported and it worked fine with MVEL before 2.2.3.

There is only github project now for MVEL and seems no way to submit a bug or ask for help from its users/developers community. Any hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Update. This error can be seen only with MVEL.eval(..) but MVEL.executeExpression(compiled) still works well.